# Why does Python magic timeit function return a syntax error?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the python magic function %timeit, but it returns a syntax error:

```
%timeit sum(range(100))
  File "<input>", line 1
    %timeit sum(range(100))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error returns in both console and debug contexts.

It is like %timeit is an unrecognised module, but I can't see anyway to import/add the magics and in any case I thought they were part of the standard Python library.

I'm using Python 3.10 in PyCharm 2022.1.2 (Community Edition)

I hope I'm not missing something obvious!

Comment: Those are provided by IPython and other such tools; they aren’t part of the standard Python library or standard REPL. But you can probably install IPython and configure PyCharm to use it.

Comment: Thanks Ry - yes simple installation of IPython gave access to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` directives are an IPython convenience when running *interactive* Python code. They're commands you directly give to the interpreter. They are *not* valid Python syntax and cannot be used in actual Python source files.